# Finding the radius of a circle in a "power of point" situation.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

EDIT: As David K. noted in the comments, my problem is lacking information. Please see the comments.

[image]

In the above figure, line $g$ is tangent to circle $c$ at $B$, $\overline{AB}=2$, $\overline{AC}=x$ and $\overline{CD} = x+2$.

The original problem just asked to find $x$, which is very easy to do using Power of Point Theorem:

$x(x+x+2) = 2^2$

$x^2 + x - 2 = 0$

$x > 0$, then $x = 1$.

But now I was asked to find the radius, which looked very simple at first, but I am having a hard time to find it.

What I tried to do: Put a system of coordinates with origin on $A$, call $(h,k)$ the center and $r$ the radius, then $(1-h)^2 + k^2 = r^2$ and $(3-h)^2+k^2 = r^2$, which lead me to the conclusion that $h = 2$. But couldn't go further to find $k$ and then determine $r$.

Comment: I think you need additional information to find the radius. The given setup will work for any sufficiently large radius such that at least some points on the circle are within $1$ unit of $A.$ There is a minimum radius for which it is possible to set up the problem; is that what you're supposed to find?

Comment: I was just asked to find "the radius", as if it was a well defined quantity. But I understand your point, it really looks like the problem is lacking information to me now. Do you think the solution for $x=1$ that I did using Power of Point also doesn't make sense in this problem?

Comment: I think your solution is perfectly fine for the given information. As long as the circle is large enough to find a point at distance $1$ from $A$, you can take that point as $C$ and then the next intersection on the same line through $A$ will be $D$ with $AD=4.$ Hence $CD = 3 = AC + 2.$ The power of a point guarantees this. If the circle were too small we could not set this up, but the assertion that we *have* such points $C$ and $D$ implies that the circle is not too small.